# Java logging API events to file

Tags: java, spring, logging, log4j

I am currently working on a system where we can not log API events to a database. E.G. User is requesting to access X service for Y product. or User failed to receive X. or User successfully received X.

**My question**

What is a good practice and what are good technologies to log events (good, neutral and bad) to a file?

**My Solution**

Since we can not log to a database, we can log to a file. I was thinking about using log4j to log different events to different files. It seems like I can setup different logging of files and settings by doing something similar to.

```
log4j.logger.ServiceLogName=INFO, ServiceLogName
```

Comment: Ideally you'd log to a remote syslog server (over IPSEC preferably), so that logs cannot be modified in the event of an attack. SLF4J is a good option these days

Answer (score 0):

`Log4j` is a open source and widely used logging api and I would recommend to store all your logs to file.

**log4j.properties**

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender

#Redirect to Tomcat logs folder
#log4j.appender.file.File=${catalina.home}/logs/logging.log

log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\logigng.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

**See Also :**

- [REST JAX-RS Logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31616523/rest-jax-rs-logging/31616649#31616649)